# MobileFirst Platform Studio 6.3.0- Error during deployment of mobilefirst app to the development server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-studio

When I am trying to run the mobilefirst application on the mobilefirst development server,

1. A notepad is opening, with a warning stating, "The filename, directory name, or the volume label syntax is incorrect.
2. I am getting this error

   ```
   [ERROR   ] FWLSE3002E: The resource is not found.
   FWLSE3041E: No MBean found for MobileFirst project 'Project'.Possibly the MobileFirst runtime web application for MobileFirst project 'Project' is not running. If it is running, use JConsole to inspect the available MBeans. If it is not running, full error details are available in the Worklight Development Server Eclipse Console view.
   ```

How can I overcome this, to check my application output?

Comment: Provide more information: did you install MFP in a location with spaces ("program files")? What is your Java version? What is the app name? project name? are there any special characters in the names?

Comment: I have installed MobileFirst Platform Studio 6.3.0 from the eclipse marketplace. My Java version is v8. My app name is 'PocketDoctor'. Project name is 'PocketDoctorProject'.(I have changed the name of the project in the above provided error code) My application and project name did not have special characters in the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java 8 is not supported in MobileFirst Platform.

You need to downgrade to either Java 6 or 7 and try again. See if the issue then disappears.

Other than that, the only reason why this would happen in Windows is if ANYWHERE in the path of filename of ANYTHING there are special charatecters: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2030845/file-directory-volume-label-syntax-incorrect.html

To double-check:

1. Place the Eclipse folder in C:\
2. Call it the directory "eclipse"
3. Place the workspace next to it.
4. Call it "workspace"
5. Open Eclipse and create a new project and application
6. Call them "MyProject" and "MyApp"

The error should not happen.

Comment: I have downgraded to Java SE 6 update 32, but still the error is persisting. I was able to deploy the app to the MF development server, but unable to see the result. The notepad is being opened with the same popup, I have mentioned earlier.
When I am trying to preview the app, by right clicking on the app, and selecting the option, then also the same notepad is being opened with the same popup

Comment: What "notepad"? do you mean a "dialog"? a window?

Comment: Now that you have downgraded, try with a fresh workspace and new project

Comment: I tried the same with a fresh workspace and a new project. But, still, the same window(notepad) is being opened.. with a warning stating, "The filename, directory name, or the volume label syntax is incorrect."